# Synchronise clocks on ubuntu running in EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ntp

I've got three servers running on AWS EC2 using official Ubuntu AMIs using paravirtualisation. I have noticed their clocks are out of sync by about a minute.

NTP is not installed by default in the official AMIs. Apparently NTP will not function correctly on VMs. Apparently you don't need to syncronise clocks, because the VM should use the same clock as DOM0, i.e. the host machine. Presumably AWS run NTP on their host machines.

On the other hand there are plenty of blogs telling you to run NTP and disable host clock syncronisation by running `echo 1 > /proc/sys/xen/independent_wallclock`. However in the official AMIs there is not /proc/sys/xen - there is /proc/xen, but it is empty.

Does anyone know how to synchronise clocks on ubuntu running in EC2?

Answer (score 3):

I contacted Amazon about this, they said that it's safe to install NTP and that you shouldn't have to disable the xen wallclock. They said that NTP is a good solution for EC2 instances.

Amazon have dedicated NTP servers which should be added to /etc/ntp.conf:

```
server 0.amazon.pool.ntp.org
server 1.amazon.pool.ntp.org
server 2.amazon.pool.ntp.org
server 3.amazon.pool.ntp.org
```

So it's probably best to install NTP as described [in the docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/NTP.html):

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

Comment: Amazon docs, "these are public NTP servers in the pool.ntp.org project, and they are not owned or managed by AWS. There is no guarantee that they are geographically located near your instances, or even within the AWS network", so these probably arent any better than standard ubuntu.pool ntps